# dojo/dijit and Printing

Tags: javascript, printing, dojo

I want to be able to provide a button to my users to just print a particular portion of my dojo/dijit application.  There seems to be a general lack of documentation and examples when it comes to printing.

For example, I have a specific `dijit.layout.ContentPane` that contains the content that I would like to print, but I wouldn't want to print the rest of the document.  I have seen some pure JavaScript examples on the web where the `node.innerHTML` is read into a "hidden" iframe and then printed from there.  I suspect that would work, but I was wondering if there was a more dojo centric approach to printing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to go down the path of reading into `<iframe>` and printing from there, but because I am using a rendered dojox.gfx surface, a direct read from the target ContentPane to the invisible iframe did not work correctly in some browsers.  So what I do is set the "src" of the iframe to a page which re-renders the diagram and then prints itself out when it is finished.  In the main document it looks something like this:

```
<iframe id="printIFrame4" src="#" style="width: 0px; height:0px; 
  border: none; background: transparent"></iframe>
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" style="margin-top: -3px;" id="buttonPrintMap4">
  Print...
  <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="event">
    dojo.byId("printIFrame4").src = "logmap/docMap.php?id=4";
  </script>
</button>
```

And then the page does the necessary dojo stuff to redrew the diagram and then once it is loaded it does a:

```
this.focus();
this.print();
```

Which then follows through with the printing.

Comment: Just came across this.  I think frames are no longer in vogue.  Just a warning for anyone else who find this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a print-only stylesheet while the first rule hiding everything by default:

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, a second CSS rule, also in your print-only stylesheet, displays only the Dojo content pane:

```
#contentPaneId {
    display: block;
}
```

The Dojo `ContentPane` ID needs to match what you use for `#contentPaneId` in the CSS.

Finally, you can instruct browsers that it's a print-only CSS file using `media="print"` in your `link` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printOnly.css" media="print"/>
```

Comment: I should add that the CSS rule "display: none" will force the layout to fill in where the item used to be.  The rule "visibility: hidden" will leave the item's dimensions in the layout but hide the item.

Comment: We are talking about an application that can easily have 100s of different classes, of which I don't directly control because I am using a framework.  While ideal, it is not practical and not very dojo centric.

Comment: I edited my original answer to provide a method that uses IDs instead of classes and should be less work than changing all of those classes.